# What would the Visual Basic code be for an Always On Top Option?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Always On Top Tool Strip Menu option and I cant figure out the code that would make it stay on top of other windows when checked, and vice-versa when unchecked. Can you please help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set "always on top," set `myForm.TopMost = True` from your menu option. See the [Form.TopMost documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx).

To un-set it again, set `myForm.TopMost = False`.

Comment: Ahh I found the problem... I had to enable the CheckOnClick property for the always on top option

Answer (score 7):

To toggle whether the `Form` is the `TopMost`, simply change the property `Form.TopMost`.

For example, to set the Form to be on top, use this:

```
Form.TopMost = True
```

To disable `TopMost`, use this:

```
Form.TopMost = False
```

Comment: This code just makes the always "always on top". I would like to give the user the choice to turn on and off always on top.

Comment: @Tyler Malo To turn it off again, call `TopMost = False;`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used to handle the event if you want it user-driven. You will obviously want to create a checkbox named `chkAlwaysOnTop` of course.  It can also be easily stored in the user settings to keep it state-aware between instances.

```
Private Sub chkAlwaysOnTop_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkAlwaysOnTop.CheckedChanged
    Me.TopMost = chkAlwaysOnTop.Checked            
End Sub
```

You'll want this in your program if you want to save said state for the user:

```
Private Sub MainActivity_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    My.Settings.AlwaysOnTop = chkAlwaysOnTop.Checked
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

You'll also want this in your form load:

```
 Me.TopMost = My.Settings.AlwaysOnTop
 chkAlwaysOnTop.Checked = My.Settings.AlwaysOnTop
```

If you're interested in what I used this in, it's here: [Rubber Stamp](http://rubberstamp.azurewebsites.net/) (Includes source code link)

Answer (score 0):

It can be:

```
Me.TopMost = true
```

or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

To have it toggled On and Off use:

`TopMost = CheckBox1.Checked`

Just make sure you replace `CheckBox1` to whatever you are using.